# Could Dark Matter be found by building a Hadron Collider that is the size of the earth?

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter, particle-accelerators

I believe that through the current Collider created by CERN is finding out new data on a small scale. What if Dark matter could be found by an even bigger Collider like one that could be built around the world?

Comment: For all countries to unity to have the largest particle accelerator the covers that wraps itself around the world. That would be a site to see.

Comment: One big problem is that it is not *feasible*. If you want to discuss this theoretically, then sure, such an accelerator could give us valuable information about the Universe,

Comment: Some would argue that the current LHC was not feasible but here it is.

Answer (score 0):

Dark matter is a label, it is used to define whatever casuses stars to orbit galaxies at a constant angular velocity. Dark matter is by no means required to be a type of matter, it is not even required to be a field effect. In short, dark matter, is just a label for whatever is causing galaxies to behave in a way that contradicts expectations.

As such, there is no requirement for dark matter to be made of particles, which means there is no requirement for it to be detectable with a particle accelerator.

Comment: With the current LHC we were able to find  the Higgs boson and that was leaps and bounds. What if the LHC was a EHC (Earth Hadron Collider) I feel would exposed the Dark Matter and give greater information.

Comment: @user174252 The Higgs is an entity in a well understood theory (electroweak) for which we already had good confirmatory evidence. Neither the less when the Higgs search started people didn't know the mass range to search. It wasn't until the Higgs mass was constrained that anyone because talking about building a Higgs generator (what became the LHC). With dark matter we're starting even further in the weeds: we don't even know if it should be a particle.  In other words the current answer to your questions is a shrug: it's not time for the question yet.

Comment: Researchers have already been able to infer the existence of dark matter only from the gravitational effects it seems to have on visible matter. Dark matter seems to outweigh visible matter roughly six to one, making up about 27% of the universe. The matter we know and that makes up all stars and galaxies only accounts for 5% of the content of the universe.

Comment: Energy/Momentum could infer their existence from the amount of energy and momentum that is gone after the collisions done by the LHC.

Comment: @Tim: Dark matter as a type of matter would explain more observations than just the angular velocity of stars in galaxies. For example it would explain the gravitational lensing of background objects beyond the Bullet cluster. Dark matter as a type of matter is also an ingredient for the understanding of the structure of the cosmic microwave background.